# OrderByChild adding one more element to the result

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get just the events that a certain user has, the thing is that after doing `orderByChild()` it's filtering one more event that I don't want.

### The code

```
//I find the user that belongs to a certain Tutor
        mDatabase.child("tutorjugadores").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshotJugador) {
                for(final DataSnapshot snapshotJugadoresTutor : dataSnapshotJugador.getChildren()){
                    if(dataSnapshotJugador.exists()){

                        //If the user has not assisted to a certain event, I get the user that belongs to the user and get the event ID
                        mDatabase.child("asistenciasjugadores").orderByChild(snapshotJugadoresTutor.getKey()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshotEvento) {
                                for(DataSnapshot snapshotEventos : dataSnapshotEvento.getChildren()){
                                    //Getting the event key from that user

                                    String eventKey = snapshotEventos.getKey();
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Event : "+eventKey + "  of the user "+snapshotJugadoresTutor.getKey());
                                }


                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Now, this is my database structure

[image]

### The problem

Now, when I run this code and execute the log to get the event for the user `2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63`, I'm getting one more event that does not belong to that user, that event is this one `-LU930PpCaQXT8CvUbc8`

### My log

> **Event** : -LU930PpCaQXT8CvUbc8 **of the user** 2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63
>
> **Event** : -LTRz61EcBUx-RLSSEaU **of the user** 2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63
>
> **Event** : -LTSGFGdW1nQbtd9HOBh **of the user** 2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63
>
> **Event** : -LTSIG_lqckgHEZ1q9YS **of the user** 2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63

As you can see, is listing all the events for that user, but that user only has 3 events associated with it.

When I order with this line

```
.orderByChild(snapshotJugadoresTutor.getKey())
```

I'm expecting to get just the nodes with the userID `2UHHZWR6B8P9XJPuLYrAg6aEgN63` and then loop and get each event ID from that user, but instead, I'm getting the event ID from this user as well `GVD0bLDf41VDdraN67mXjAS6KPk1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't filter with a string by only using JSON based databases like Firebase.
And *orderByChild* only changes the sorting of the returned values. So you are basically ordering all the values under that key, there is no filtering going on. 
After this point you have 3 options to go on.

***Option 1 - Not efficient, recommended for only small apps:***
You can order all the values and do the filter afterwards.

***Option 2 - Recommended:***
You can change your data structure. Create another node like "UserEvents". Under it store UID's. And under that UID's there should only be that user's events.

***Option 3 - Recommended and functional:***
You can use Elasticsearch. It's great for complex queries. You can use it with Firebase with Google Cloud Functions after you switched to " Pay as you go " plan or you can integrate another server with Firebase database by using Flashlight extension.

Comment: Thanks for your help , yes, I already hav the UserEvents node, thats why I need to get this specific ids from each user and then go to that table in order to pull the values :) , I will keep trying with another ways, thanks, will wait if no one more answers I will mark this as correct

Comment: @GastónSaillén As I know orderByChild only gonna change the sorting of the query, not the returned results. Could you please verify that?

Comment: thats absolutly correct, I was missing that point , thats why I was getting 4 values instead of just the 3, Im trying to add a little if condition to just filter the results wher the user id is the same as the searched one

Comment: Thanks mustafa for the hint, now Im querying the events node, getting all the keys going to the assistence node and check if the user ther eis the same as the one I requested

Comment: Just fixed the problem with the above :)

Comment: @GastónSaillén You are welcome, glad I could help (: